# Are there "portable" versions of Opera for Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: versions, opera, portable

I want to use the latest Opera  browser, but v12 does not have opera-unite anymore. So, I would like to use a "portable" v11 Opera (v11 has `unite`).

(By `portable` I mean a program with all files within a certain directory that can be put in any place on the hard drive or on an external drive, a program that can be started by running an `executable` file from the same directory, and which can be run separately of other installed versions of the same program.)

Comment: The Concept of "portable" is not applicable in Linux, you can get the program already in a precompiled form from the developer in a tar.gz file (Firefox for example), Opera should provide it like that just don't select deb when downloading.

Comment: @Uri Herrera: please edit my question so as to avoid my naive use of the term but keeping the purpose as specified now between brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had a deb file of opera11, I would try to make the "portable" version.

There is a ready-to-use opera package [opera-11.64-1403.i386.linux.tar.bz2](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/opera-11.64-1403.i386.linux.tar.bz2), [other packages](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/)

Comment: thanks. http://www.opera.com/browser/download/?os=linux-i386&ver=11.64&local=y

Comment: No need. there is a ready-to-use opera package [opera-11.64-1403.i386.linux.tar.bz2](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/opera-11.64-1403.i386.linux.tar.bz2) [other architectures](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/)

Comment: that is the answer. please post is as such, so I would make it definitive

Comment: This tarball version did work, but only older versions seem to be available from http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly good question.
Although portable apps are not usually available under Linux,
they definitely have their place.

You can find a portable version of Opera 11.50 at :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/?source=navbar

I just found it myself and haven't yet tested it.
My use case for this type of application is primarily being able to continue
using important apps when my computer is temporarily disabled by some software
problem, which is not rare under Linux.  (But had occurred too often under
the Microsoft environment before I migrated full time to Linux.)
I just need to boot with any (linux-based) recovery disk, and thus function
normally for few days it might take for my system to return to normal.

In case you're interested, there is another application called "cde" which
is supposed to let you "create" a portable app, by putting all the
requirements in a directory with the application :

www.pgbovine.net/cde.html

Again, I haven't yet tested it.
Good luck :)

Comment: And how do you launch that portable app ? I'm interrested.

Comment: @MrVaykadji - this is outdated now, but the answer is that you run the executable from the folder, i think this is how seamonkey works for example